# dimple d3 plot, average of the values, quick command fix

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

Want to make a plot with the average values of HR and avg. Looked it up in the documentation, but it seems i cannot get the average command to work :(

Can anybody spot my stupid mistake ?

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
  d3.tsv("bbd3.tsv", function (data) {
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    myChart.setBounds(75, 30, 490, 330)
    myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "HR");
    myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "avg");
    myChart.aggregate = dimple.aggregateMethod.avg;
    myChart.addSeries( ["handedness"], dimple.plot.bubble);
    myChart.addLegend(180, 10, 360, 20, "right");
    myChart.draw();
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jPFkiV80guNUJtSmxFc1NjN1E/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation applies to the series not the chart.  So you can rewrite like this:

```
var mySeries = myChart.addSeries( ["handedness"], dimple.plot.bubble);
mySeries.aggregate = dimple.aggregateMethod.avg;
```